# Could not build with Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I encountered this issue from Xcode beta, and recently I downloaded 10.2, the bug has not been fixed and I could not build my project at all. Does any one have the same problem and do you know how to solve it?

I attach a screenshot for your information.

[image]

Appreciated your help.

Comment: Do you have `load` class methods?

Comment: Hi, yes, a few objective-C classes implement load method. However, non of mine Swift classes override it, probably come from 3rd libs. I will check it.

Comment: In my case, there was a problem with SwinjectStoryboard and Firebase cocoapods.